# jena ExceptionInInitializerError

Tags: eclipse, exception, jena

i'm jena newbie and I have this error:

```
  Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.RDFReaderFImpl.<clinit>(RDFReaderFImpl.java:74)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.impl.ModelCom.<clinit>(ModelCom.java:54)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:142)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.rdf.model.ModelFactory.createDefaultModel(ModelFactory.java:136)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.vocabulary.OWL.<clinit>(OWL.java:37)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.ProfileRegistry.<clinit>(ProfileRegistry.java:47)
    at com.hp.hpl.jena.ontology.OntModelSpec.<clinit>(OntModelSpec.java:53)
    at myprogram.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:46)
```

Where the code part that jumps into this exception is this (Connection.java:46):

```
 m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null );
```

The userlibrary I defined contains:

```
commons-codec-1.5.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.3.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4
jena-arq-2.9.4.jar 
jena-core-2.7.4.jar 
jena-iri-0.9.4.jar 
jena-tdb-0.9.4.jar 
log4j-1.2-16.jar 
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar 
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar 
xercesimpl-2.10.0.jar 
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
```

Java version is jdk1.7.0_11

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you try catching that exception and printing out getCause() or getException() (I think they do the same thing)? That will provide the actual error.

Comment: I've added this but error is still the same: console shows nothing new, pheraps i do something wrong!?! 


`public OntoConnection(String path) {
  try {
   m = ModelFactory.createOntologyModel(OntModelSpec.OWL_MEM, null);
  
  } catch (Exception e) {
   System.out.println("cause:"+e.getCause()+";");
   System.out.println("message:"+e.getMessage()+";");
   System.out.println("stacktrace:"+e.getStackTrace()+";");
   
  }`

Comment: Apologies, I wasn't very explicit. That exception is just a wrapper for the underlying issue, which getException / getCause will return. Try something like `System.out.printf("Underlying issue: %s\nMessage: %s\nStacktrace: %s\n", e.getCause(), e.getCause().getMessage(), e.getCause().getStackTrace());`

Comment: nothing happened... but these code worked good since was on another machine... i think is something wrong with the libraries... versions of jdk, jena, o.s....

Answer (score 0):

AWT-EventQueue-0 -- what environment are you running in?

One possibility is that there is another version of Jena around because stacktrace does not quite align with the 2.7.4 codebase.

Comment: i'm using jdk 1.7.0_11 and the all lib in this list:
antlr-runtime-3.2.jar
arq-2.8.7.jar
aterm-java-1.6.jar
core.jar
forms-1.3.0.jar
gnujaxp.jar
iri-0.8.jar
iscwt.jar
isrt.jar
itext-2.0.6.jar
jade.jar
javase.jar
jaxb-api.jar
jbig2.jar
jcommon-1.0.12.jar
jetty.jar

Comment: jfreechart-1.0.9.jar
jfreechart-1.0.9-experimental.jar
jfreechart-1.0.9-swt.jar
jgrapht-jdk1.5.jar
jPod.jar
junit.jar
junit-4.5.jar
jxl.jar
lucene-core-2.3.1.jar
miglayout15-swing.jar
mysql-connector-java-3.1.14-bin.jar
owlapi-bin.jar
owlapi-src.jar
pellet-cli.jar
pellet-core.jar
pellet-datatypes.jar
pellet-dig.jar
pellet-el.jar
pellet-explanation.jar
pellet-jena.jar
pellet-modularity.jar
pellet-owlapi.jar
pellet-owlapiv3.jar
pellet-pellint.jar
pellet-query.jar
pellet-rules.jar
pellet-test.jar
piccolo.jar
piccolox.jar
relaxngDatatype.jar
servlet.jar
stax-api-1.0.1.jar

Comment: swtgraphics2d.jar
wstx-asl-3.2.9.jar
xsdlib.jar
jcl-over-slf4j-1.6.4.jar
commons-codec-1.5.jar
httpclient-4.1.2.jar
httpcore-4.1.3.jar
jena-arq-2.9.4.jar
jena-core-2.7.4.jar
jena-iri-0.9.4.jar
jena-tdb-0.9.4.jar
log4j-1.2.16.jar
slf4j-log4j12-1.6.4.jar
xercesImpl-2.10.0.jar
xml-apis-1.4.01.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
icu4j-3.4.4.jar

Comment: any suggestion? do u find some problem whith all these lib? for sure in another machine with similar configuration... (but i don't remember that!) this program works! it's really withering!

Comment: ok! yes... it was something wrong with too much jena jars or something like this. i've just eliminated all jars and inserted into project step-by-step! result? no more problem and project now works with the half of jars present before! Tnx for your support!